# Bootstrap- Applying Nested Grid Columns properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would appreciate any help given, I've been stuck for a few hours. I've made an accordion page and I want the page to end up as two columns on desktop mode which stack into one column as you resize down to mobile and tablets.

Code- http://codepen.io/Ahhmmogh/pen/KpoReG

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-8"
```

I've used http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_grid_ex3&stacked=h as a reference but I haven't been successful at all as you can see. What am i doing wrong? Again any help would be awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your piece of code:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVvZev

Since it was missing the bootstrap css I have added some extra css which should be discarded when bootstraps is available. Your html wasn't valid either.

Basically what I did was this:

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-6">
         ... this content is full width on xs which is the smallest bootstrap viewport size. and half on sm or higher.
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-6">
         ...
     </div>
 </div>
```

Hope this will help you any further. I mad both columns evenly wide because otherwise I looks strange that to are next to each-other. But if you want that you should do this:

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-8">
         ... this content is full width on xs which is the smallest bootstrap viewport size. and half on sm or higher.
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-4">
         ...
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This did it, I understand where I went wrong. Thank you for your help

Comment: When I view in mobile mode, the page still doesn't stack. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the codepen not work in your mobile view? It should work.

Comment: When I download and open the index, it doesn't stack in mobile mode, just makes 2 smaller columns side by side.

Comment: You should resize your window to mobile size. Which will probably be around 480 pixels or smaller to see it wrap below the other one. Bootstrap uses its media queries to adjust the behavior on the size of the screen.

Comment: When I open the codepen link I've added with my phone I can press on 3 red button all the way down. 1x 0,5x or 0,25x. 1x is the actual mobile size which wraps the menu below eachother.

Answer (score 1):

very simple

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
        left content
        xs: 12 cols / sm and higher: 8 cols
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        right content
        xs: 12 cols / sm and higher 4 cols
    </div>
</div>
```